# Bokeh graph doesn't plot properly

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

The following code doesn't generate a graph:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from datetime import datetime

output_notebook()

TOOLS="hover,crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,zoom_in,zoom_out,box_zoom,undo,redo,reset,\
    tap,save,box_select,poly_select,lasso_select,"

df = pandas.read_csv('./logs.csv')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
xvals = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
yvals = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

p = figure(title="Test Title", width=500, height=500, \
           x_axis_type="datetime", y_axis_type="datetime", \
           x_range=(df.iloc[-1]['datetime'].strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),\
                    df.iloc[0]['datetime'].strftime('%Y/%m/%d')),\
           y_range=('00:00:00','23:59:59'),\
           tools=TOOLS)
p.scatter(xvals, yvals, alpha=0.5)
show(p)
```

This graph produced is a blank graph. What is the problem?

EDIT:

I updated the code with

```
xvals = df['datetime'].dt.date
yvals = df['datetime'].dt.time

p = figure(title="Activity history", width=800, height=500, \
           x_axis_type='datetime', y_axis_type='datetime',\
           x_axis_label="Date", y_axis_label="Time",\
           tools=TOOLS)

p.scatter(xvals, yvals, alpha=0.3)
show(p)
```

And this produces a graph.

Comment: Would be more helpful to get a sample of the df to have a full running code. Do you get any error message in the browser console? And your y_range is not datetime objects

Comment: `dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')` seems suspect, since it discards the date part of the datetime. Are you trying to group/aggregate by hour? If so, that takes more pandas work to do. Here is an example that bins a bunch of data by Day of Week that could be useful to compare: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#adding-jitter If that's not what you are after you need to explain your use case more, include enough data for people helping to try and run it, maybe include a link to a similar plot so that folks can have some idea what you are after.

Comment: Additionally you should check the browser JS console for errors. Pretty all the actual work in Bokeh happens in the browser, so many errors will only show up there.

Comment: @seb if I passed in a time value it returned a ValueError. Looks like only a str is accepted. I updated the code anyway which is suffice for my needs at the moment.

Comment: @bigreddot - no I am not trying to bin a bunch of data by DoW. That would be frequency based graph. I am just plotting "activity", i.e. date (x), time (y).

Comment: @bigreddot There are warnings "could net set initial ranges" in the JS console even wihen the scatter graph produces a satisfactory result. Not sure whether those are false-positives though.

Answer (score 1):

OK, as far as I can tell, this is what you want (using some project sample data, since you did not provide anything to run your code with):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.commits import data

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", y_axis_type="datetime")
p.circle(x=data.index, y=data.index.time)
show(p)
```

[image]

The `datetime` axis type, as the name suggests, treats the timestamps as datetimes. I.e., these are interpreted as hours of the day in the first day of the first year of Epoch. That's why the axis starts and ends with *1/01* and *1/02*. You might want to use [customize the tick formatter](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/1.0.4/docs/user_guide/styling.html#tick-label-formats) to display just the hours.

For reference, `data` looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Looks like (for me at least) the tick formatter is poorly documented for how to achieve 1h interval labels with the DatetimeTickFormatter: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter